# javafx background thread issue ?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, javafx, synchronous

I am trying to launch a background thread in the start of my javaFX application, but my UserInterface(UI) freezes nevertheless.  this is what i am doing :

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {         
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:visuAgent.db");
                c.setAutoCommit(false);
                Statement stmtt = c.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = stmtt.executeQuery( "select max(num_step) from avoir_continent " );               
                rs.close();
                stmtt.close();

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(rafraichirbd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(rafraichirbd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }        
        }
   });       
        return null;
    }
};  

                Thread th = new Thread(task);
                th.setDaemon(true);
                th.start();
```

Any idea ?thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Platform.runLater()` inside your Task's `call()`. The Platform.runLater() `takes you back to the UI thread`.

Try removing it, while doing the computation and use it only when you need to update some data on the UI